# Drupal fancybox views gallery - display only first item of attached images

Tags: drupal, gallery, fancybox, drupal-views

I have multiple images attached to a node that act as a gallery using fancybox.
In views I am attempting to only display the first attached image.

The idea is to only display the first image then when clicked, fancybox will go into gallery mode displaying all subsequent attached images.

I have tried the 'Group multiple values' showing '1value' starting from 0.

This works for only displaying the first item, but unfortunately when clicked fancy box does open but not in gallery mode. It just displays the first item.

What i need to do its open all attached images as a fancybox gallery but from only the first item.

Any help or ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Print all anchors to gallery images but make them hidden except the first one. 
Make sure they all have the same "rel" tag and apply fancybox as usual. Then you should be able to navigate gallery after clicking on the visible anchor.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Could you please elaborate on how this can be done. Would it be within views, a views theaming template or elsewhere? Thanks for your time.